# Changing bitrate of Exo Player

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, exoplayer

This question might have been asked many times. I searched everywhere but could not find the correct answer. I am using ExoPlayer in my project to play HLS videos.

I want to give user the option to select the bandwidth of videos. Something like what YouTube does.Any idea how this can be achieved using ExoPlayer?

Comment: you have to provide multiple video urls with diffrent bandwidths and depending on the selected bandwidth you have to provide the correct video url to exoplayer.

Comment: Hi prit. If you have solution. please post your answer. I will offer my bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ExoPlayer issue tracker:

> ExoPlayer currently selects the first variant listed in the master
>   playlist. If I remember correctly, this is what Apple
>   recommends/specifies as correct client behavior. If you want to start
>   in the lowest quality, you should technically have your server
>   generate the master playlist with the lowest quality listed first.
>
> The above aside, we do agree that it makes more sense for the client
>   to make the initial variant selection locally, as opposed to the
>   recommended behavior. We'll be moving HLS over to use FormatEvaluator
>   in ExoPlayer V2, which will give more control over the initial
>   selection (and over the adaptive algorithm in general).

And as the solution, this comment:

> Have a look at AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory. Its parameters may
>   provide enough customization for your case.

I think this should give you either the answer you need, or it will guide you in the right direction.

Note that you **have to provide** streams in lower qualities to be able to use this. **If you ONLY have the video in HD, ExoPlayer can't downsample the video**, its not its job and not what it is intended for. ExoPlayer can only sync and enable smooth transition between the video in multiple resolutions when they are provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i will check

Comment: can you explain how to add multiple quality video urls(720p,540p,360p,240p) to exoplayer and make exoplayer automatically select the suitable url based on network speed

Comment: Its something that needs to be done on the backend side, unfortunately I don't know that part. AFAIK the URL delivers a manifest of sort which contains all links in a key-value list but you will need to check the specifics there :(